# How can I set the tintColor of a UIBarButtonItem via the appearance protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I'm trying to programatically set the `tintColor` for `UIBarButtonItems` throughout my project. I'm calling:

`[UIBarButtonItem appearance]`

However, after looking at Apple's documentation here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

I found no such properties for setting the `tintColor`. The closest related methods I could find were:

```
setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:
setBackgroundImage:forState:style:barMetrics:
```

However, both of these methods are for setting an actual background image. Is it not possible to simply set the button's `tintColor` via `UIAppearance`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe I dont understand the question correctly. But if you look in the link that you've posted, under Tasks -> Customizing Appearance, there's a property called tintColor.

You just have to set that property to the desired color

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Is this not working for you?

Comment: I see but how would you target different styles or states of the button? For example a button with the state: UIControlStateDisabled and the style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone it seems there are no methods providing the necessary styling. Usually a done button is a different tint than the standard bar button item.

Comment: Well yes, the UIAppearance protocol is not that flexible, at most you can use appearanceWhenContainedIn: method, to provide a more specific target (eg. a specific toolbar inside a specific controller) to tint, but if you need separate stylings for button states, you'll have to stick to using custom images

Comment: It's working fine with iOS 5 and iOS 6 version but not with iOS 7.
 In iOS 7, it's giving an exception: 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-setTintColor: is not allowed for use with the appearance proxy on UINavigationButton.'

Answer (score 4):

As per the `UIAppearance` Protocol, you can set the `tintColor` as below :

> To customize the appearances for instances of a class when contained within an instance of a container class, or instances in a hierarchy, you use `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` to get the appearance proxy for the class

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil]
       setTintColor:myNavBarColor];
```

This is mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance) , if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks I should be more clear though -- how can you set the tint color for a specific style: UIBarButtonItemStyleDone or control state: UIControlStateDisabled

Comment: Not sure where this going but you can add flexibility by writing a category to UIBarButton Item, which would basically take the color and state as input and you can manually create a UIImage from that color and then use the method : 
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics